# php trouble with get ajax request with json

Tags: php, ajax, json

I'm using this code for send my data to the server

```
ascarray = new Array();
for (var a in window.localStorage) {
    var ascrray = ascarray.push(a, ":", window.localStorage[a]);
}
JSON.stringify(ascarray);

$(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'myphp.php',
                data: { objects : ascarray },
                success: function(data) {
                    alert('the server returned ' + data);
                }
            });
        });
```

And on server side i trying to get this request with

```
echo "I get param ".$_POST['objects'];
```

But server returned only this

```
the server returned I get param Array
```

How can i fix this? What i do wrong?

Comment: If you `echo` a variable containing an array PHP will output just the word `Array`. You need to echo the individual elements.

Comment: How about if you share us the *myscript.php* code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are echoing out an array.

just use `var_dump()` to see what's inside.

Comment: Well, just need to `json_encode` array in php. But i get something like `\u0433\u0435\` this? How can i decode this? With urldecode?

Comment: What is the output when using `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: Dont decode, if youll parse it it will become normal chars, trust me :)

Answer (score 0):

echo don't print Array content, use var_dump() to see what inside your $_POST['objects']

Answer (score 0):

try below code . call ajax when loop completed push data to array.

```
ascarray = new Array();
var i = 1;
for (var a in window.localStorage) {
    var ascrray = ascarray.push(a, ":", window.localStorage[a]);
    if(i === window.localStorage.length){
         $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'myphp.php',
                data: { objects : ascarray },
                success: function(data) {
                    alert('the server returned ' + data);
                }
            });
    }
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put this code in your ajax

```
 dataType: "json",
```

and try